# secretOrPrivateKey must have a value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jwt

I am trying to learn nodejs and using jwt to create a token for a user. But I am getting this error on my server side:  `secretOrPrivateKey must have a value`. It is a lot of code so I am going to give what I think is important (let me know if you need anything else):

**user.js:**

```
const config = require('./../config/config').get(process.env.NODE_ENV);
...
userSchema.methods.generateToken = function(callback) {
    console.log(config.SECRET); // THIS IS UNDEFINED
    var token = jwt.sign(this._id.toHexString(), config.SECRET);

    this.token = token;
    this.save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, user)
    });
}
```

**server.js:**

```
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({'email': req.body.email}, (err, user) => {
        ...    
        user.generateToken((err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);

            res.cookie('auth', user.token).json({
                isAuth: true,
                id: user._id
            })
        })
    })
})
```

**config.js:**

```
const config = {
    production: {
        SECRET: process.env.SECRET,
        DATABASE: process.env.MONGODB_URI
    },
    default: {
        SECRET: 'SUPER_SECRET-PASSWORD!123?',
        DATABASE: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/feedback'
    }
}

exports.get = function get(env) {
    return config[env] || config.default
}
```

Comment: What is the node command you are using? If you use node server.js does it return default. You can put a console.log in your exports.get()

Comment: Oh! Would you mind putting your comment in an official answer so I can mark it as the answer. I was using nodemon server.js, but when I now tried using node server.js then my service worked. Would you mind explaining why this works AND how I can make it work using nodemon, please :) I am very new to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your calling of node is probably wrong. Try node server.js and you should get the default config. You can also put a console.log in the exports.get() to see what it is sending in as an environment variable.

Comment: Perfect answer thanks man! But like I said in the comment, would you mind explaining the problem and how to get it working when I use `nodemon server.js`. Please :)

Comment: Oh wait, for some reason `nodemon server.js` is also working now. Maybe it was just a server stop and start that was necessary?

Comment: I usually use forever as my node monitor, but they will both call node in the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem with your config. The only thing you export is a function get.  so config.SECRET is empty. you should have write  config.get().SECRET

Comment: Check how I import config in user.js. There you will see I already call the .get function there...if I change it to `config.get().SECRET` then I get the error `config.get is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have this folder structure.

- Project

  - frontend
  - backend

    - index.js
    - .env

I ran into the error "secretOrPrivateKey must have a value" because the terminal was in `Project` folder and I ran `nodemon backend/index.js`. I wasn't in the correct folder with .env file to run the backend. `cd backend && nodemon index.js` helps